# вопрос с условием if в объекте JS

Tags: javascript, объекты, условия

```
let data = {
   price1: 1,
   price2: 0,
   price3: "",
   price4: 1,
   price5: 5
```

};

У меня есть объект. Нужно вывести все ключи, которые не 1, не 0 и не пустая строка. почему-то 3 параметра в условии, не срабатывают.

```
for (let key in data) {
            if (data[key] !== '' || data[key] !== 0 || data[key] !== 1) {
                console.log(key + ' ' + data[key])
              
            }       
        }
```

Comment: `||` -> `&&` ...

Comment: Так и пишите условие через `И`, а не через `ИЛИ` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Вы ведь даже на русском говорите:

> не 1, не 0, **и** не пустая строка

Так что нужно логическое И, а не логическое ИЛИ.
Замените || на &&.